# Which tool or method should be used to make text on a whiteboard look natural / right?

Tags: editing, davinci-resolve

I am not a professional video editor, but I am involved in the production of a small-scale educational video series. A main part of this video contains a teacher sitting at a table with a whiteboard next to him. There is a requirement for the whiteboard to contain text which changes as he speaks.

I would like to ask which tools / method should be used to accomplish this. I have made 2 attempts (below) but neither of them seem exactly right

**ATTEMPT 1** - This seemed 'wrong' to me as the text wasn't lining up with the whiteboard. Changing the text to dashes seems to confirm this.

[image]

[image]

**ATTEMPT 2** - I used the Yaw and Pitch controls in Davinci Resolve to try to make the lines line up with the whiteboard. My teammates agree that the dashes look better than the first attempt, but that the text in Attempt 1 looks more natural than the text in Attempt 2.

[image]

[image]

My question is simply which tools or method are generally considered best to deal with this type of thing and achieve a result that will not stick out as seeming 'wrong' to viewers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of pitch and yaw is correct, but it looks like you have just overcompensated a little. Your vanishing point for the lines is too near - that bottom line shows this by angling up too much.

If you correct them by assuming the vanishing point from the top and bottom of whiteboard, you will get a more natural look, and then your text will look more natural.

Comment: Thank you @Dr Mayhem this is very good to know. But just to clarify, is the "rotation" the same as the "roll" as I do not have a specific tool for roll in the app I am using but I do have rotation. With Yaw, Pitch and Rotation should it be possible for me to get the right perspective? It seems very difficult to do, but if you tell me that it's just a matter of tweaking these 3 controls then I will persist!

Comment: Hi Joseph - yes, those controls will do it. I haven't got a box with DaVinci on it here, unfortunately or I'd work out how much, but just tweak them a little - you aren't far off.